# Should I make my Custom Unit Test Assert Class Non-Static?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, vs-unit-testing-framework

I use the built in Visual Studio Unit Testing Tools to perform unit tests against CRM 2011.  A lot of the tests are Asserting the creation of an Entity.

```c#
Assert.IsNull(service.GetFirstOrDefault<Contact>(contact.Id));
```

(the GetFirstOrDefault is an extension method that attempts to retrieve the contact by id from CRM, and returns null if not found)

I'd like to create my own Assert method that operates like this:

```c#
CrmAssert.Exists(service, contact);
```

At first I thought it would be a good idea to inherit from `Assert`, but alas, it is a static class.  I then created a new static class like so:

```c#
public static class AssertCrm
{
    public static void Exists<T>(IOrganizationService service, T entity) where T : Entity
    {
        Exists(service, entity, null, null);
    }
    public static void Exists<T>(IOrganizationService service, T entity, string message) where T : Entity
    {
        Exists(service, entity, message, null);
    }

    public static void Exists<T>(IOrganizationService service, T entity, string message, params object[] parameters) where T: Entity
    {
        if (service.GetFirstOrDefault<T>(entity.Id) == null)
        {
            throw new AssertFailedException(message == null ? String.Format(message, parameters));
        }
    }
}
```

Called like so:

```c#
AssertCrm.Exists(service, contact);
```

This is fine, except that I really should be able to set the service, once, and not have to call it each time:

```c#
AssertCrm.Service = service;
AssertCrm.Exists(contact);
AssertCrm.Exists(campaign);
AssertCrm.Exists(etc...);
```

But I believe that Visual Studio will attempt to run tests multi-threaded, which means that when I set the `Service` static property, it could be overridden by a different service in a different test (As well as `IOrganizationService` not being thread-safe).

Do I need to make my AssertCrm class non-static so I don't have to worry about mutli-threading?  Is there a simpler technique that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research I didn't find any reason that it should (has to) be a static class, and have since created it as a non-static class.

One note to anyone else thinking of doing something similar:  Do create static method overloads for all of your instance methods since `ClassName.AssertMethod()` really does make more sense a majority of the time vs `new ClassName().AssertMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the AssertCrm as a singleton and then you could instantiate it once and all other calls will use the same instance..

Comment: Except that doesn't prevent multi-threading issues with the IOrganizationService.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer the first option with the use of the built in assertions library.  I don't see what benefit you're getting from trying to wrap this in an extension method or "helper".

If you really want to go down this route you could create a set of extension methods on `IOrganizationService` to remove the need to keep passing it in.  Makes it a bit cleaner but I'm still in favour of the first.

```
crmService.AssertExists(contact);
```

As an aside, why are you hitting a real CRM instance in your "unit" tests?  Much quicker and more maintainable to verify against a mock `IOrganizationService` within your tests.

Comment: I actually did think about going down the route of making extension Methods on the IOrgnainzationService.  I didn't like it as much because you still have IOrganizationService defined multiple times.  What if CRM 2013 comes out with an entirely different SDK?  You get to hand touch of usage of it, verses the single time that you set the property for each test.

Comment: Who's to say that I'm not mocking the IOrganizationService?  It's just an interface.  When I want to actually test that an entity was actually created in CRM, it's kind of worthless to mock that.  The complicated part of 90% of our code base isn't the business logic, it's the queries that return the data.  If you can show me how to mock the IOrganizationService so If someone drops a column that I'm filtering against in the query it will fail, without actually hitting the CRM instance I'm testing against, I'm all ears!  ;)

Comment: @Daz - These are technically called integration tests instead of unit tests if they are hitting the CRM server, not a big deal (in my book) and I know a lot of people who call them unit tests anyways.

Comment: @Daryl - The majority of my testing in CRM Dev work is also on the queries and other interactions with the CRM platform. The Biz Logic is the easy part, ha! That said, I've moved away allowing any hard-coded strings in CRM code. All entities, attributes, option set items, relationship names, etc. must be in generated files. Then you just generate the file and build as part of your integration testing. That has eliminated a lot of problems.

Comment: @Nicknow What about FetchXml?  You can check it against an XSD, but you can't compile it!  Do you only use Linq to CRM>?  If not, how do you generate the attribute names?  Custom Utility using reflection?